# what is the probability that a prime number divides another prime plus 1?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

what is the probability that a prime number divides another prime plus 1?

what I do know is that for 2 it's 100%

I can show this fact using a function

$f(x,y):=$ the number of primes between $1$ & $y$ that when you add 1 you can divide it by $prime(x)$ and get a whole number and divide that by $π(y)$

$π(x)$ is the prime counting function

$f(1,x)=(π(x)-1)/π(x)$ because the only time $prime(x)+1$ doesn't equal an even number is when the prime is $2$.

$2+1$ isn't even.

and as the x goes to infinity $(π(x)-1)/π(x)$ goes to 100%

my question is what is the probability that $3,5,7,...$ divides a random prime number plus 1

do you know the general formula for $f(x,y)$ as $y$ goes to infinity

Comment: I can show that $2$ divides $p+1$ for all primes $p >2$ without using calculus.

Comment: yea I did go overboard all primes are odd beside 2 and odd plus 1 is, even so, I didn't need all that @TorstenSchoeneberg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you fix the first prime $p$ then you are looking for primes of the form $pk-1$ The density of this set of primes is $1/(p-1)$ in the set of all primes by the Chebotarev theorem.

Comment: thanks that makes sense